# How do you find the name of an existing full text catalog in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-catalog, sql-server-express

I have SQL Server 2008 Express installed.  Several months ago I created a full text catalog and index.  I would like to index some additional table columns now, but I can't remember the name of the existing catalog.  How do I find out the name of an existing full text catalog.

Hopefully this doesn't involve installing any new tools, because this is a production server.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

This will return the catalog names and should give you what you need.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142511.aspx):

> To find the filegroup of full-text
>   index on a table or view, use the
>   following query, where object_name is
>   the name of the table or view:
>
> ```
> SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups f, sys.fulltext_indexes i 
>    WHERE f.data_space_id = i.data_space_id 
>       and i.object_id = object_id('object_name');
> GO
> ```

I also believe that the name of files located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\FTData

should give you some idea of the name of your catalogs.

Comment: This query executes fine but does not return any data in the name column.  I know there is a fulltext catalog set up.  Also, there was nothing on disc that shed any light as to the name.